# ASP.Net Core: Output 2 tags from one tag helper

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Using ASP.Net Core's Tag Helpers, is there any way to convert 1 tag into 2 tags at the root level? I know you can remove a tag completely using `TagHelperOutput.TagName == null`, but I'm wondering how I can do the opposite to output more than one tag.

For example, go from:

```
<canonical href="/testing" />
```

to:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.examples.com/widgets" />
<link rel="next" href="http://www.examples.com/widgets?page=2" />
```

Here is an example tag helper that outputs one of the tags, but not both:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("canonical")]
public class CanonicalLinkTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public string Href { get; set; }
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "link";
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("rel", "canonical");
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute(new TagHelperAttribute("href", new HtmlString(Href)));
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried removing the tag and using `output.PostContent.AppendHtml`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/th-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1), once you have used `TagHelperOutput.TagName == null` to remove your tags, you must be able to add custom HTML using `output.PostContent.AppendHtml()`

**Update**

`PostContent` is only to append after. To replace entire content you will need to use `output.Content.SetHtmlContent(`

Answer (score 3):

TagHelpers can output any amount of html you need, just use output.Content to write output. Here is a basic example:

```cs
[HtmlTargetElement("canonical")]
public class CanonicalTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public string Link1Rel { get; set; }
    public string Link2Rel { get; set; }
    public string Link1Href { get; set; }
    public string Link2Href { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = null;

        outputLink(Link1Rel, Link1Href, output);
        outputLink(Link2Rel, Link2Href, output);            
    }

    private void outputLink(string rel, string href, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        TagBuilder link = new TagBuilder("link");
        link.Attributes.Add("rel", rel);
        link.Attributes.Add("href", href);
        link.TagRenderMode = TagRenderMode.SelfClosing;

        output.Content.AppendHtml(link);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```html
<canonical link1-href="https://link1.com" link1-rel="canocical" link2-href="https://link2.com" link2-rel="next"></canonical>
```

Output:

```html
<link href="https://link1.com" rel="canocical">
<link href="https://link2.com" rel="next">
```